Why doesn't a string or character comparison works in Python3?
So, I have been doing a question in leetcode and I usually do it in c++. Plus I tried doing it in python3 this time. when I wrote :
token[i]>=47 and token[i]<=57 

It showed me an error that comparison doesn't work . Now , I am a noob in python . So, please tell me the logic behind this. Like, I know this statement would have worked in C++. as I comparing the ASCII values. But it doesn't in python.

A Python string is a series of Unicode code points, not just ASCII characters.

A (single-character) str isn't just an unsigned integer in disguise like a char in C++ is. There's no implicit conversion of (for example) 'A' to 65, either; you have to be explicit:
47 <= ord(token[i]) <= 57

or
chr(47) <= token[i] <= chr(57)  # '/' <= token[i] <= '9'

Python is more strongly typed than C/C++; it doesn't blur the distinction between a character and an integer just because it would be slightly more efficient to do so.

str.isdigit(token) would be a more typical solution in Python.

@guidot But that would differ for '/' (and hundreds of other characters).

I'm only addressing the type error, not the best way to detect a digit.

@chepner I find it hard to agree with Python being more strongly typed, but I guess the term is not defined well enough to make a comparison.

In what way to do you think Python is not more strongly typed than C++?

The whole duck typing thing? In Python, if you define a class with all the same methods and attributes as other class, it will work just fine in its place. In C++ this will fail at compile time.

That's an issue of static-vs-dynamic typing, not strong-vs-weak typing.

@chepner what is strong-vs-weak typing, though?

In python, the function (method) ord() is used to get the ASCII value of character. So you can provide it with a character like so:
ord('A') # -> 65

Another approach would be to use the chr function with the ASCII value as its arg to convert it to a character like so:
chr(65) # -> 'A'

Finally I think the best way would be to just compare that index with the actual character. See this example:
token = "mystring"
print(token[0] == 'A') # -> False

